# how to ping the IP_OF_WORKSTATION

Tags: turtlebot, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

what is the procedure of how to  ping this when i am using the turtle bot system and the OS is the Ubuntu 12.04 version
it prompt me for "unknown host IP_OF_WORKSTATION"

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/142591/how-to-ping-the-ip_of_workstation/) by [Rizwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/13506/rizwan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-03-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to replace IP_OF_WORKSTATION with the IP address of your workstation.

For example, if the IP address of your workstation is 192.168.42.42, you would do:

```
ping 192.168.42.42
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0